# Como ativar o Migrations para o Identity em Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Eu preciso desacoplar o Identity da minha camada Asp.net core MVC e jogá-lo para outra camada crosscutting de meu projeto DDD. Baseando-me no projeto Equinox do Eduardo Pires, eu consegui fazê-lo, só que estou encontrando dificuldades para ativar o Migrations. Para que vocês entendam o que fiz:

1 - Criei a camada SistemaComercial.Presentation.Web.MVC com autenticação de usuário. Automaticamente, o sistema criou várias pastas, controllers, e classes necessárias para o funcionamento da autenticação, inclusive o banco de dados local. Fantástico!!!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Criei uma camada SistemaComercial.Infra.CrossCutting.Identity.Data e manualmente, criei as mesmas pastas, controllers e classes da camada mvc. A Ideia é ativar o Migrations nesta camada e depois eu remover tudo da camada MVC e desta forma, o funcionamento seria desacoplado e na camada Identity.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu tento executar "Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context: ApplicationDbContext", aparece a seguinte msg de erro:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
>         User profile is available. Using 'C:*\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows
>   DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest. More than one DbContext named
>   'ApplicationDbContext' was found. Specify which one to use by
>   providing its fully qualified name using its exact case.

```js
 //Minha classe de contexto na camada Identity
 
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            // get the configuration from the app settings
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            // define the database to use
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionpg"));
        }
        
    }
```

Alguém sabe como me ajudar a ativar o Migrations na camada Identity criada?

Link do projeto: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=40838E65B9F8787E%21120&cid=40838E65B9F8787E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ele esta reclamando porque você possui dois contexto com o mesmo nome (ApplicationDbContext.cs) dentro de sua solução.

A solução é excluir o seu Context da sua camada MVC ou renomear o nome de algum dos contextos, já que você especifica o nome do contexto na linha do powershell:

```
-Context: ApplicationDbContext
```

Comment: Olá Gabriel! Removi o contexto do MVC, mas agora está dando este erro: "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time."

Comment: Na hora de executar o powershell, selecione o projeto onde esta o contexto.

Comment: Eu estou selecionando o projeto SistemaComercial.Infra.CrossCutting.Identity.Data, só que fica aparecendo o erro..

Comment: Compartilhe seu contexto com a gente

Comment: Vou inclui-la na postagem... Qualquer coisa, se quiser, pode baixar o projeto no link acima para olhar mais detalhadamente.... :)

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9415#issuecomment-327589912

Comment: Eu criei a classe de implementação e a pasta MIgrations foi ativada. Só que quando dou Update-Database, ele dá este erro: Keyword not supported: 'port'.

Comment: Adicione `--output (seu diretório)` logo a frente do comando.

Comment: Falha minha... Deu certo dar o Update... Era que eu estava fazendo por outro banco de dados... Ele estava tentando fazer a inserção das tabelas em outro banco kkkkkkk Foi mal.

Comment: Assim: Add-Migration Initial_Start -Context: ApplicationDbContext --output Data\Migrations?

Comment: É que eu estou fazendo pelo Package Manager Console...

Comment: No package manage console deve-se usar  -OutputDir ... Consegui!

Comment: Posta sua resposta Gabriel para que eu a marque como respondida... Obrigado :)

Comment: Estamos comentando direto na minha resposta.

Comment: Certo.. Nem tinha observado rsrsr... Valeu mano :)